# What have been the dates on which the state of alarm in Spain for Covid-19 has been extended?

Tags: covid-19, spain, state-of-emergency

The pandemic began in March 2020 and I know that the state of alarm has been extended 6 times.

I would like to know the dates on which the government has announced an extension of the state of alarm each time

Comment: What has your [preliminary research](https://home.kpmg/xx/en/home/insights/2020/06/flash-alert-2020-268.html#:~:text=State%20of%20Alarm-,The%20State%20of%20Alarm%20in%20Spain%20has%20been%20extended%2C%20for,sixth%20time%2C%20until%2021%20June.&text=The%20validity%20of%20Royal%20Decree,valid%20through%2021%20June%202020.) revealed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of alarm was first declared on March 14th under Ley Orgánica 4/1981 - on states of alarm, exception and siege. [Article Six of Chapter II](https://www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-1981-12774#asexto) states:

> One. The declaration of the state of alarm will be carried out by
> decree agreed in the Council of Ministers.
>
> Two. The decree will determine the territorial scope, the duration and
> the effects of the state of alarm, which may not exceed fifteen days.
> It may only be extended with the express authorization of the Congress
> of Deputies, which in this case may establish the scope and conditions
> in force during the extension.
>
> <sub>(translated from original)</sub>

Because the initial declaration & the extensions all required Royal Decrees, this makes each extension easier to pinpoint. The initial declaration was enacted by [Royal Decree 463/2020, of March 14](https://boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-2020-3692). At the end of this page, there are references to the six other Royal Decrees which extended the state of alarm - these are [Royal Decree 476/2020, of March 27](https://boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-2020-4155), [Royal Decree 487/2020, of April 10](https://boe.es/buscar/doc.php?id=BOE-A-2020-4413), [Royal Decree 492/2020, of April 24](https://boe.es/buscar/doc.php?id=BOE-A-2020-4652), [Royal Decree 514/2020 of May 8](https://boe.es/buscar/doc.php?id=BOE-A-2020-4902), [Royal Decree 537/2020, of May 22](https://boe.es/buscar/doc.php?id=BOE-A-2020-5243), and finally, [Royal Decree 555/2020, of June 5](https://boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-2020-5767). The state of alarm ended at 00:00 on June 21st.